# flex-box, keep a first line unwrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container where I need inner blocks following each other and behave like floated ones. I cannot use float as the layout should re-arrange after a resolution changes. Currently, I need both the blocks 1 (70% width) and 2 (30%) reside the same line, but a second one moves itself to the next line:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div>Header</div>
  <div>SideRight</div>
  <div>Bottom line</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width:300px;
}
section > div{
  padding: 10px;
}

section > div:nth-child(1){
  background-color: pink;
  width: 70%;
}

section > div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: lightgreen;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 30%;
}

section > div:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can see the live example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/f6LWiQfpRUwYYyW9Dve4?p=preview

So, is it possible to achieve? Finally, it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `section` and remove the `flex-direction: column;` like this

```
section {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  max-width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;    //add this
}
```

if you want the 'Bottom line' fill the entire row add `flex-grow: 1;` to `section > div:nth-child(3)`

The final result will be something like this

```
section {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */    
  max-width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;           //new
}

section > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;              //new
}
```

[Here a working example](https://codepen.io/yandylvl/pen/WYMZrb)

Answer (score 1):

Do you explicitly NEED to use column display for this section? If not, this is easy to achieve with `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent section and then setting a percentage `width: 100%` to the last child element. You also have to remove `flex-direction: column` from the parent.

[Here's an updated example for you which produces the desired result](https://plnkr.co/edit/acOs0fwSmcfa1kCS8pGV?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

I changed your flex-direction to a flex-wrap and set the 3rd div to 100% width. Hope this helps :)

```
  <head>
    <style>
      body *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      section{
        background: #ddd;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width:300px;
      }
      section > div{
        padding: 10px;
      }

      section > div:nth-child(1){
        background-color: pink;
        width: 70%;
      }

      section > div:nth-child(2){
        background-color: lightgreen;
        align-self: flex-end;
        width: 30%;
      }

      section > div:nth-child(3){
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <section>
      <div>Header</div>
      <div>SideRight</div>
      <div>Bottom line</div>
    </section>

  </body>

</html>
```